# Way to express a number in its most compact sum of powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, power-series, exponential-sums, exponential-polynomials

Given a non-negative number **n**, what is the best approach to find the most compact representation for **n** in terms of sums of powers, such that the bases and the exponents can't surpass a given value (for instance, $2^{32}$)?
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i(\beta_i)^{\gamma_i}$$

The gammas are the exponents and are limited in range (they are non-negative integers and can't surpass $2^{32}$). The betas are the base and are limited in range (they are positive integers and can't surpass $2^{32}$). The alphas are non-negative integers (they are not limited in range). The objective is to minimize how many powers the sum has. That is, once the coefficients (alphas) specify how much powers we have in total, we want to minimize the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i$$

Given **n**, the challenge is to solve the problem without relying on some brute-force technique.

Crossposted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278990/way-to-express-a-number-in-its-most-compact-sum-of-powers

Comment: You can use LaTeX on this site instead of linking to images.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that, Chris Wuthrich!

Comment: The formula at the top suggests that you can't reuse an exponent more than once, thereby preventing one from expressing $13 = 3^2 + 2^2$ -- is this intentional?

Comment: I had not thought of that, Adam P. Goucher. That was not intentional.

Comment: I reformulated the question in order to reflect what I really wanted to say. Thank you!

Comment: Please try to wait at least a week or so before you cross-post to another site, and then provide a link when you do. You asked basically the same question just under a day ago at MSE at [Way to express a number in its most compact sum of powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278990/way-to-express-a-number-in-its-most-compact-sum-of-powers).

Comment: Sorry, John Omielan. I'm new to the site(s). I just thought asking in more places would bring in more answers. I'll follow your advice from now on.

Comment: @DaviFN No worries. FYI, I believe the main reason you should provide a link is as a courtesy to help people avoid duplicating each other's efforts. As for the amount of time to wait, as far as I know, there's no official policy on that. I just recall reading a week being mentioned by somebody else's comment in a similar situation. As for why you should wait, it just sometimes takes time for the right person to find & answer your question. It might not have to be a week, but I suggest you should usually wait at least several days.

Comment: @DaviFN To at least a certain extent, any method to use depends on the range of $n$, e.g., is it allowed to be on the order of a googolplex. However, even for reasonable sizes, I don't think there's any general method which is necessarily much better than brute force. Nonetheless, note there are some fairly small upper bounds on the $\alpha$ sum. For example, the $1936$ paper [On Waring's Problem for Fourth Powers](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s2-41.2.143) gives a proof every sufficiently large integer can be represented as a sum of $17$ fourth powers. ...

Comment: @DaviFN (cont.) The $2012$ paper by William C. Jagy (who I believe is a member here) and Irving Kaplansky of [Sums of Squares, Cubes, and Higher Powers](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10586458.1995.10504318), regarding an integer being expressible as "... two squares and a cube with everything positive, computations support the possibility that there are only finitely many exceptions". There are other similar type results you can find. However, as far as I know, basically none of the proofs or conjectures are constructive, i.e., they show existence but not how to find the values.